# Как кластеризовать текстовые данные с помощью карт Кохонена и SOINN?

Tags: python-3.x, нейронные-сети

В общем, я провел обработку текста и получил матрицу TF-IDF. Теперь, я как понимаю, надо подать её на входные нейроны. Я пробовал делать следующее (матрица tf-idf = tfidf_matrix получена заранее с помощью пакета **Sklearn**)

```
import som as som

new=tfidf_matrix.toarray()
somm = som.SOM('name', new, mapsize = None, norm_method = 'var',initmethod='pca',neigh='Guassian')
somm.train(n_job = 1)
```

initialization method = pca, initializing..
initialization done in 0.003000 seconds
rough training...
radius_ini: 1.000000 , radius_final: 1.000000, trainlen: 6
epoch: 1 ---> elapsed time:  0.001000, quantization error: 3.036220 
epoch: 2 ---> elapsed time:  0.001000, quantization error: 2.983431 
epoch: 3 ---> elapsed time:  0.001000, quantization error: 2.623276 
epoch: 4 ---> elapsed time:  0.001000, quantization error: 2.623276 
epoch: 5 ---> elapsed time:  0.001000, quantization error: 2.623276 
epoch: 6 ---> elapsed time:  0.001000, quantization error: 2.623276 
finetune training...
radius_ini: 1.000000 , radius_final: 1.000000, trainlen: 8
epoch: 1 ---> elapsed time:  0.000000, quantization error: 2.623276 
epoch: 2 ---> elapsed time:  0.000000, quantization error: 2.623276 
epoch: 3 ---> elapsed time:  0.001000, quantization error: 2.623276 
epoch: 4 ---> elapsed time:  0.001000, quantization error: 2.623276 
epoch: 5 ---> elapsed time:  0.000000, quantization error: 2.623276 
epoch: 6 ---> elapsed time:  0.001000, quantization error: 2.623276 
epoch: 7 ---> elapsed time:  0.001000, quantization error: 2.623276 
epoch: 8 ---> elapsed time:  0.001000, quantization error: 2.623276 
Total time elapsed: 0.015000 secodns
final quantization error: 2.623276

```
som_labels = somm.project_data(new)
S = pd.DataFrame(data=som_labels,columns= ['label'])

a = S['label'].value_counts()
a = a.sort_index()

a = pd.DataFrame(data=a.values, index=a.index,columns=['label'])
a
```

index   label
0   20
1   5
3   1
5   5

Кластеры я получил, но как теперь мне это интерпретировать графически? И верно ли я обучаю сеть?

Comment: Эта задача ещё актуальна?

Comment: Если да, то скажите, как Вы храните матрицу и что Вы хотите от такой обработки данных?

Comment: @hedgehogues Матрицу я получаю опять же с помощью **sklearn** 
 `from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
  n_featur=200000
  tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.8, max_features=10000,
                                 min_df=0.01, stop_words=stopwords,
                                 use_idf=True, tokenizer=token_and_stem, ngram_range=(1,3))
get_ipython().magic('time tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(titles)')
print(tfidf_matrix.shape)`

Comment: @hedgehogues хочу получить графическое представление (сами карты) сообщений, распределенных по кластерам.